# How to load data dinamically with RecycleView in KIVY, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to add data to a sqlite3 database in order to read, add and delete them from a RecycleView dynamically, but I'm not being able to make them load automatically after uploading my data to the database.

This is a part of my code that I would need to modify to make it work. Thank you very much.

```
producto=[]

def cargarproductosbase():
    global producto
    con = sqlite3.connect("base.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select nombre from producto")
    print("se cargaron los productos")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        for i in row:
            producto.append(i)
            print(producto)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    print ("cargue estos datos")
    print (producto)

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
    cols=2

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            aceptar=AceptarDonacion()
            aceptar.open()

            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class ExampleRV(RecycleView):
    global producto
    cargarproductosbase()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global producto

        super(ExampleRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.reloading, 1)

    def reloading(self, nothing):
        global producto
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in producto]
        print (producto)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate class `cargarproductosbase()` in the constructor of class `ExampleRV`.

## Snippets

```
class ExampleRV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global producto
        super(ExampleRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        cargarproductosbase()
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in producto]
        print(producto)
```

## Output

[image: RV - data loaded]

Comment: Trythat and it does not work either, although it does the registration of the product, at the time of going to the screen where I show that data, the program shows the data that I read when the class was executed at the beginning.thank you

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you share a print screen of what is not working? Is your app having problem reflecting the updated data in RV?

Comment: This is my project, https://github.com/sbritos58/Imagine

The program is for my first year project of programming and I chose kivy thinking that it would be the most practical.
the program is in Spanish, what it allows to do is create a donation with a user and be able to request it with another type of user with a recycleview.
If you notice after entering a donation it does not appear when you want to see it as a donee without leaving the program.
You are very kind to help me.
Thank you.